# Is USB RAM or a USB processor a feasible concept?

Tags: usb, memory, cpu

Is USB RAM or a USB processor a feasible concept for development?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to put useful special-purpose processing power out at the far side of the USB bus, but it's not very practical for a general-purpose processor. So it's not like you're going to be able to upgrade your slow Pentium M by popping a Core i7 USB dongle into the side of your machine.

A real-world example of useful special-purpose processing power over USB are those USB dongles that contain dedicated H.264 encoder hardware to accelerate re-encoding video files. The [Elgato turbo.264 HD](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Turbo264HD/product1.en.html) is one such device.

FireWire could conceivably be a better choice for trying to add external general-purpose processing power to a system. FireWire doesn't have USB's restrictive Host vs. Device dimporphism; FireWire devices are all peers on a network. FireWire devices can do DMA transfers to each other, so you could conceivably craft something of a [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access) system via FireWire links. Intel's upcoming [Light Peak](http://techresearch.intel.com/articles/None/1813.htm) optical interconnect is another possibility.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but would be so slow to be useless.

Windows Vista introduced a feature called ReadyBoost which uses a USB stick sort of as a RAM extension.  Since USB is so slow compared to RAM, it would use the USB stick as a faster alternative to the hard disk's pagefile.

A general-purpose processor connected over USB would be so slow as to be pretty useless except in perhaps a very specialized situation.

- For comparison, the [peak bandwidth of USB2 is 480 Mbit/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB2#Overview), whereas the [peak bandwidth for DDR2-5300 is 5333 Mbyte/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Chips_and_modules), which is 88 times faster.
- Flash memory's write and read speeds doesn't come close to USB2's maximum throughput.
- The [latency of DDR2-5300 is around 6ns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB2#Overview), while the [latency of USB flash drives is on the order of 1-10ms](http://www.dansdata.com/quickshot039.htm), which is *hundreds of thousands* times slower.

Comment: How would a USB CPU be possible? The busses for USB connect to the CPU for processing, how could this happen if the CPU was connected through that bus?

Comment: @MarkM The poster is asking about a processor, not necessarily a CPU.  A GPU is a processor, but is not the computer's CPU.  I think the spirit of the question is about hypothesizing some sort of auxiliary or add-on CPU to boost computer speed.

Answer (score 3):

USB 2.0 has a maximum bandwidth of 480Mbps. DDR3 1600 has a bandwidth of 12800MBps. Notice the b vs B.

This is certainly not plausible. CPUs would be even more bandwidth limited.